# Подсчет ячеек со значениями по дате, совпадающей с текущей

Tags: google-apps-script

Имеется 2 столбца, один с датой в числовом формате (вставляется автоматически, при вводе в 3-ем столбце), второй с цифрами. Необходимо по сегодняшней дате, соответствующей дате в первом столбце, считать соответствующую ей строку со второго столбца с цифрами.

Не получается сравнить по дате, как написать правильно на месте `?????`?

```js
function snachPoData() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Пробник");
    var diap = sheet.getRange("b2:b16").getValues();
    var diap2 = sheet.getRange("a2:a16").getValues();

    var res = 0;

    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < diap.length, i < diap2.length; i++, j++)  
    {
        if(diap[i] == ????? && diap2[j] == 1) 
        {
            res += 1;
            sheet.getRange("a17").setValue(res);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Первый столбец в таблице - это b или а? Проверьте, у Вас diap и diap2 не нужно местами поменять?

Comment: diap2[j] == 1 - и что вот это означает? Вы же строку второго столбца должны подсчитывать, а не сравнивать, насколько я понял из описания проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы сравнить две даты можно использовать метод `getTime()` для приведения объектов к простому типу:

```
return date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();
```

Иногда требуется округлить даты до дней, чтобы сравнить их:

```
Date.prototype.roundToDay = function(){
  var res_ = new Date(this.valueOf());
  res_.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return res_;
}
```

Теперь

```
return date1.roundToDay().getTime() === date2.roundToDay().getTime();
```